# Difference between probabilities $1+O(1)$, $1-O(1)$ and $O(1)$

Tags: probability

**Question 1**: What is difference between probability $1+O(1)$, $1-O(1)$ and $O(1)$?

**Question 2**: Which one is higher and which one is smaller?

Example:
http://www14.in.tum.de/personen/raab/publ/balls.pdf

page 3.

Comment: When using Big O notation, we usually need a bit of context to figure out what's meant.  Where did this come up?  Do you have specific examples?

Comment: @MarcusM Thanks I'll add it into the question.

Comment: I have never seen big O notation used in probability like that. In standard use, all these three things mean the same thing

Comment: @Wojowu I have added a link.

Comment: Usually (or at least in my experience), Landau notations are unsigned (i.e., $o(1)$ could be either positive or negative): one would write $f(x)+o(1)$ regardless of whether the negligible term is positive, negative, or changes sign.
However, I have seen several times CS papers and authors write the sign, to emphasize the fact that the quantity is negligible but negative, for instance. (In this case, the negligible or O(\cdot)$ quantity is assumed to be nonnegative).

Comment: For probabilities (that have to be in $[0,1]$, however, I'd say that $\pm (1)$ is quite... confusing. $1 = 1-0 = 1/2+1/2 = 1/2+O(1)=1-O(1)=O(1)$ all seem valid to me, and $1+O(1)$ for a probability only makes sense if the asymptotic term can take negative values anyway (a probability > 1 is a nonsense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is little o notation, not big O notation, which makes quite a big difference.  If we have have $a_n = 1 + o(1)$, where $a_n$ is sequence with parameter $n$, this means that $a_n$ is equal to $1$ plus some term that goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.  For instance, if we have $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$, then $a_n = 1 + o(1)$.  Similarly, if we had a different sequence with $b_n = n + o(n)$, the $o(n)$ term goes to zero when we divide by $n$ and take $n \to \infty$.  We could write this is $b_n = n(1 + o(1))$ by factoring out the $n$.

Consider this more real-world example. Define $$a_n = \frac{(n + 1)^3}{n^2}$$.  Then we note that $\frac{a_n}{n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.  We can rewrite $a_n$ as $$a_n = n(1 + o(1)),$$ 
which illustrates that $a_n$ is roughly linear in $n$.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that $a_n=1-o(1)$ goes to 1 for a big value $n$.

Comment: @user153465, Yes, that is exactly correct.